# Creating Table using array

Tags: tables, arrays

I'm trying to create entry similar to tables using array

```
begin{array}{*{20}{r}}
   {}| & A |& B  \\
\hline
   A_1| & {one|} & {two}  \\
   B_2| & {three|} & {four}  \\
\hline
 \end{array}
```

Is there any way to draw continuous vertical lines? (something like `hline` for drawing horizontal lines?)

Comment: Put `|` into column argument, say `begin{array}{|*{20}{r|}}`, and you will get what you want.

Comment: @Ch'enMeng ; Thank you for solution and correcting typos; my English is not good, i'll try my best to avoid typos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
%\begin{array}{*{20}{r}}
\begin{array}{|*{3}{r|}} % because later only 3 columns
%   {}| & A |& B  \\
{} & A & B  \\
\hline
%   A_1| & {one|} & {two}  \\
 A_1& {one} & {two}  \\
%   B_2| & {three|} & {four}  \\
 B_2 & {three} & {four}  \\
\hline
 \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Every vertical line in the description of columns (`r|`'s here) produces a vertical line through the whole array. I understand that your `one` to `four` words are only artificial ones.